# Doctrine: how to map an aggregate or scalar to an entity in one query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been searching for a while but can't find any examples of what I want to do, most of the discussion is about lazy loading.

What I want to do is map the byproduct of a query to my entity but not have that property persisted/stored in the database.

In this query for example I select a distance and I want to be able to access that value through $entity->GetDistance() without having to recalculate the value in PHP land.

```
$queryBuilder->addSelect('GEO_DISTANCE(:latitude, :longitude, job.longitude, job.latitude) AS HIDDEN d')
->having('d < :distance')
->setParameter('distance', $distance)
```

How can I map "d" to the entity with one query?

Comment: you could use a DTO in conjunction of the new statement as [described here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax)

Comment: That looks like it could work but unless I'm wrong it means you have to maintain the exact properties you want which adds additional steps whenever you want to modify your entity.

Comment: I guess it might be easier to just remove "HIDDEN" so that d is returned in the result set, then loop through calling $entity->setDistance() for each result?